# Entity Framework Core 6/7 skips null keys in GroupBy if it is a subquery

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

If I query like this:

```cs
query.GroupBy(x => x.Field).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

I'll get `[null, "v1", "v2"]` which is fine because some entries had null in `x.Field`.

If, on the other hand, I use the same query inside of another query

```cs
query
    .Take(1)
    .Select(x => new 
    { 
        x.Field2, 
        distinctValues = query.GroupBy(x=> x.Field).Select(x => x.Key).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

I'll get `{Field2: "some value", distinctValues: ["v1","v2"]}`.

Why is that and what workaround do I have? (Distinct fails to translate too often).

Comment: Why `GroupBy` instead of `Distinct`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv "(Distinct fails to translate too often)"